# Sorting Winforms TreeView in a type safe way?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics, treeview

Is it possible to sort a `TreeView` collection using `IComparer<T>` and not `IComparer`? After all they are all `TreeNode` values, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean via [`TreeViewNodeSorter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter.aspx), then it must be an `IComparer` (in short, it pre-dates generics). You could write something that shims this, but it probably isn't worth the trouble...

```
public static class ComparerWrapper
{ // extension method, so you can call someComparer.AsBasicComparer()
    public static IComparer AsBasicComparer<T>(this IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return comparer as IComparer
            ?? new ComparerWrapper<T>(comparer);
    }
}
sealed class ComparerWrapper<T> : IComparer
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> inner;
    public ComparerWrapper(IComparer<T> inner)
    {
        if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
        this.inner = inner;
    }
    int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return inner.Compare((T)x, (T)y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Is it at least possible to have a custom Sort method to sort them. I guess that's not possible due to the TreeView controller.

Comment: By that I mean a custom sort that I can call that will not cast things from object to TreeNode.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that tripped me up was that IComparer comes from System.Collections whereas IComparer comes from System.Collections.Generic.

I originally only had
`using System.Collections.Generic;`
and was getting a compile error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApp.NodeSorter' to 'System.Collections.IComparer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

The solution was to add
`using System.Collections;`